# We're square/even/quits in formal speech

Tags: differences, formality

What are the differences between: **be square, be even and be quits**?

Are they acceptable to use in formal speech? If they not, what should I use instead?

Comment: It depends on the context. They are only equivalent in certain contexts, and they mean different things in different contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are **even** with someone, you do not owe them anything, such as money or a favor:

> You don't owe me. I don't owe you. We're **even**. *(informal)*

If two people are **quits**, they are on even terms, especially because a debt or score has been settled:

> I think we're just about **quits** now, don't you? *(informal)*

If two people are **square**, one of them has paid off a debt to the other and neither now owes or is owed any money:

> I paid you back, so we're **square**. (*informal* according to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/square))

Since all the three adjectives are informal, I suggest using "***debt-free***", for example (the word is not formal though; I'd say it's neutral):

> The company's virtually **debt-free** status gives it the flexibility to consider larger deals.
>
> The family business is healthy and completely **debt-free**.

"Debt-free" can be used to talk about not only companies but also people:

> Whether we’re there yet or not, many of us hope to be **debt-free** and continue living that way.

Comment: As I see quits, square and even are interchangeable, aren't they?
And what if I say _We are debt-free_ (we don't owe each other anymore). I mean with a plural pronoun.
How does it sound?

Comment: @THEWaterfall they are. And yes, you can say "we are debt-free".

Comment: @THEWaterfall *"The couple decided it was time to call it quits."* That is an idiomatic expression for "break up." The other words (*square* and *even*) cannot be used interchangeably in that phrase. Also, *"Let's be square with each other."* can be taken to mean, *"Let's be honest with each other."* The other words cannot be substituted in the same sense. So, no. The words are *not* always interchangeable. This answer just gave a specific context where they are. Don't take it as a general statement.

Comment: @JasonBassford Oh, my mistake, I wanted to know the difference in the context of the meaning _not to owe someone anymore_. Though, thank you for telling the other meanings of those contrusctions.

Comment: @JasonBassford what I meant is that the words are interchangeable if they mean not owing anything. I thought it was clear from the definitions and examples I had given. Noting was said about calling it quits or any other idioms meaning something rather than owing money.

Comment: @Enguroo Nothing in the question itself gave any context at all—certainly nothing about owing money. It seems that was just an assumption (even if correct).